# Qual é a função do wrap_content?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
    RelativeLayout onCreateLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    onCreateLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ClickMeParms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  (
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

    ClickMeParms.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    ClickMeParms.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O [`WRAP_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT) é uma propriedade que define o tamanho (altura ou largura) da *view* baseado no seu conteúdo. Este valor indica que o tamanho deste elemento deve se ajustar ao conteúdo atribuído a ele.

Veja um exemplo abaixo, no qual a altura do `LinearLayout` será proporcional ao tamanho da *view* `Button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Em outras palavras, deve ocupar apenas o espaço que necessitar(altura e/ou largura) para exibir suas informações no layout.

Veja essa pequena ilustração abaixo no qual a marcação laranja representa um `LinearLayout` com propriedade `wrap_content` na altura na imagem da esquerda e `match_parent` na imagem da direita.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tem como função informar que a view ou layout deve ser dimensionada de forma a ter o tamanho suficiente para mostrar todo o seu conteúdo, incluindo qualquer *paddind* definido.

**Como funciona.**

O desenho do layout é processado em duas passagens: "medição" e "posicionamento".

Cada uma das passagens percorre a "árvore de views" desde o topo à base.
Durante a passagem "medição" cada view na "árvore" informa as suas  especificações de dimensão e calcula a sua dimensão. No final todas a views tem guardada as suas dimensões.

A passagem "medição" usa a classe [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) para comunicar dimensões. Ela é usada pelos objectos "filhos" para dizer aos "pais" como eles querem ser medidos e posicionados. A classe base ViewGroup.LayoutParams apenas descreve o quão grande a view quer ser tanto para a largura quanto para a altura.

Para cada dimensão, ela especifica um dos seguintes valores:

- Um número exacto.
- MATCH_PARENT, que significa que a view quer ser tão grande quanto o pai (menos *padding*)
- WRAP_CONTENT, significa que a view quer ser suficientemente grande para incluir seu conteúdo (mais *padding*).

Durante a passagem "posicionamento" cada view "pai" é responsável por posicionar cada "filho" usando os tamanhos calculados na passagem "medição".